# asp:GridView No actualiza datos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un problema con un `asp:GridView` que no está actualizando datos, en el HTML tengo lo siguiente:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ResultadosTest" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered bs-table" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No existen datos que mostrar" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="NombreServicio" HeaderText="Seccion" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Resultado" HeaderText="Resultado" ReadOnly="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Y en *Code behind* al cargar la página:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("NombreServicio", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Resultado", typeof(bool)) });
        ResultadosTest.DataSource = table;
        ResultadosTest.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Posteriormente con un botón que recoge datos y llena un `DataTable` (se comprobó que el `DataTable` si trae datos):

```
protected void GoPruebas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ResultadosTest.DataSource = ValidacionesServicio(chkBoxAmbientes.Items[i].Value).Result;
     ResultadosTest.DataBind();
}
```

Pero los datos no se muestran, ¿qué estará fallando?

Comment: puedes revisar esta propiedad AutoGenerateColumns="false"

Answer (score 0):

Probé tu código hasta cierto punto y funciona, ¿puedes probar creando una tabla con valores literales y asignándola al DataSource del gridView en lugar de usar el método ValidacionesServicios?

Algo así:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[2] { new DataColumn("NombreServicio", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Resultado", typeof(bool)) });
        table.Rows.Add("Prueba servicio","true");
        ResultadosTest.DataSource = table;
        ResultadosTest.DataBind();
    }
```